Incorrect display size of RPPreviewViewController
I built the preview of ReplayKit with RPPreviewViewController, but for some reason it ignores safe area on my phone. None of the modalPresentationStyle help, tried everything. How can I fix this?
        ZStack {
            MapViewRepresentable(entryStore: entryStore, manager: manager)
                .disabled(true)
                .onAppear {
                    
                }
                .opacity(isRecording ? 1.0 : 0.0)
            
            ZStack {
                if !isRecording {
                    
                    Text("App Logo and Title")
                        .foregroundStyle(.white)
                } else {
                    
                }
            }
        }
        .overlay(
        
            ZStack {
                
                if isShowPreviewVideo {
                    rp
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                }
                
            }
        
        )
        .navigationBarBackButtonHidden()
        .onChange(of: isShowPreviewVideo, perform: { i in
            
        })
        .background(Color.black.ignoresSafeArea())  // Ensure the background covers the entire screen

    struct RPPreviewView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        let rpPreviewViewController: RPPreviewViewController
        @Binding var isShow: Bool
        
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }
        
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> RPPreviewViewController {
            rpPreviewViewController.previewControllerDelegate = context.coordinator
            rpPreviewViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
            
            return rpPreviewViewController
        }
        
        
    }


